# My disabled button does not work, it does not take into account the style Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

I had set up a disable system if my form fields are not filled in and I want to move it to a custom component but the problem is that it doesn't work anymore, I think I have targeted the problem but I don't see how to solve it. I guess because it doesn't find my this.email, this.password etc. If you can help me please

```js
<template>
  <button
    class="btn"
    :class="{ 'btn--disabled': !validatedFields }"
    :disabled="!validatedFields"
  >
    <slot></slot>
  </button>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ["disabled"],
  computed: {
    validatedFields() {
      if (this.signup) {
        if (this.email != "" && this.password != "") {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      } else {
        if (this.email != "" && this.password != "") {
          return true;
        } else {
          return false;
        }
      }
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../scss/main.scss";
.btn {
  width: 100%;
  margin: 1rem 0;
  background: $secondary;
  color: #ffff;
  border: none;
  padding: 1rem 2rem;
}
.btn--disabled {
  color: red;
}
</style>
```

```js
<template>
  <section>
    <div class="form">
      <transition name="test" mode="out-in">
        <form key="login" v-if="login" @submit.prevent="login">
          <h1>Connexion</h1>
          <custom-input
            icon="fa-at"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="email@gmail.com"
            @updated="updatedEmail"
          />
          <custom-input
            icon="fa-lock"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Mot de passe"
            @updated="updatedPassword"
          />
          <custom-btn>Connexion</custom-btn>
          <p @click="login = !login">Déjà un compte ?</p>
        </form>
        <form
          action=""
          key="signup"
          v-else
          novalidate
          @submit.prevent="createAccount"
        >
          <h1>Inscription</h1>
          <custom-input
            icon="fa-at"
            name="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="email@gmail.com"
            @updated="updatedEmail"
          />
          <custom-input
            icon="fa-lock"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Mot de passe"
            @updated="updatedPassword"
          />
          <custom-input
            icon="fa-lock"
            name="RepeatPassword"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Répéter votre mot de passe"
            @updated="updatedPassword"
          />
          <custom-input
            icon="fa-user"
            name="name"
            type="text"
            placeholder="John"
            @updated="updatedName"
          />
          <custom-file />
          <custom-btn>Inscription</custom-btn>
          <p @click="login = !login">Pas de compte?</p>
        </form>
      </transition>
    </div>
  </section>
</template>

<script>
// import signup from "../assets/signup.jpg";
// import connex from "../assets/connex.jpg";
import CustomInput from "./Input.vue";
import CustomBtn from "./Button.vue";
import CustomFile from "./FileInput.vue";
export default {
  components: {
    CustomInput,
    CustomBtn,
    CustomFile,
  },
  data() {
    return {
      login: true,
      file: null,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onFileChanges(event) {
      let files = event.target.files || event.dataTransfer.files;
      if (!files.length) return;
      this.file = files[0];
    },
    updatedEmail(email) {
      this.email = email;
    },
    updatedPassword(password) {
      this.password = password;
    },
    updatedName(name) {
      this.name = name;
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style lang="scss" scoped>
@import "../scss/main.scss";
section {
  padding: 2rem;
  .form {
    background: #ffff;
    box-shadow: 0px 15px 16.83px 0.17px rgb(0 0 0 / 5%);
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 2rem;
    h1 {
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 1.8rem;
      margin-bottom: 1rem;
      color: $secondary;
    }
    p {
      text-align: center;
      margin-top: 1rem;
    }
  }
  .test-enter-active,
  .test-leave-active {
    transition: opacity 0.5s;
  }
  .test-enter,
  .test-leave-active {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Did you check what value has been returned by validatedFields?

Comment: You should explain what means `this.signup` and `this.email` where it comes from?

Comment: Are there any console errors? It might just be your example code, but `this.email` and `this.password` don't exist. Can you show your `data` as well? Thanks.